Oracle database transfer: database isolation
If I want to duplicate a schema with Oracle, I sometimes encounter problems with triggers or views that reference the schema name. I can search & replace the original schema name, but it is risky.
In comparison, I can duplicate a postgres or mssql database without any renaming (the schema name is kept and the database is isolated).
Can I achieve the same thing with Oracle?
Is Oracle pdb equivalent to postgres/mssql database?

A PDB  is not equivalent to a pg/mssql (not pluggable) database.
An Oracle Pluggable Database (PDB) is a self-contained database (with schemas, users, roles, datafiles, etc.) you can plug out of a service/container-db (CDB) and plug back in onto another service/container-db (CDB). Therefor the name "pluggable database". This is really powerful and behaves as a complete isolated environment where you can have your data, your users, your roles, your tablespaces and your datafiles. You can configure refreshable clones of PDBs, standby PDB, regular clone, backup PDB - everything online.
A duplicate PDB is an exact copy of the source PDB. Your data/schemas will not change.
Conceptually, you can look at "database" and "pluggable database" the same way, but introducing the "pluggable" word you have a lot more features at hand.
Best of luck!

In that case, what would be the equivalent of ps/mssql database isolation level in Oracle?

A PDB is equivalent to a mssql database.  It's a feature SQL Server has had forever with a fancy name when Oracle finally implemented it.  A SQL Server database has its own schemas, user, roles, files, backups, etc.  SQL Server instance hosts multiple databases, which all share the same server resources (memory, CPU, etc), and queries can read across databases.

@Kiruahxh In Oracle Database it would be a pluggable database (PDB). From version 23ai, the multitenant architecture is the only architecture forward - so you will store your data in one or many pluggable databases. The same as you will do using PostgreSQL and databases.
